# HTML formatted output for SQL Server Agent job

Tags: html, sql-server, formatting, exponential

I am facing an issue with the output formatting of a SQL Server query which is part of a SQL Server Agent job. My Agent job contains the following code in the only "step" it has:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = CAST((SELECT (CAST(getdate() as DATE)) as 'td'
    ,''
    ,M.[Serial Number] as 'td'
    , ''
    ,case MR.MTUID 
        when 21180200 then round(ceiling((cast(MR.RegisterRead as float)/10)),0,1)
        when 47374728 then round(ceiling((cast(MR.RegisterRead as float))),0,1) 
     end as 'td'
  FROM [StarDatabase].[dbo].[Account MTU Meter Xref] MX
  INNER JOIN Meters M on
  M.[Meter ID] = mx.[Meter ID]
  INNER JOIN NonScaledReads MR on MR.MTUID = MX.[MTU ID]
  WHERE MX.[MTU ID] IN (21180200, 47374728)
  and MR.ReadingTime >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + cast('08:00' as datetime)
  and MR.ReadingTime <= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + cast('08:59' as datetime)
  order by MR.ReadingTime
  FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Meter Readings at 04:00 AM</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Date </th> <th> Meter Serial # </th> <th> Reading </th></tr>'    

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'email',
@recipients = 'xxx@abc.xyz',
@subject = '4:00 AM Meter Reads',
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML'
```

My email output looks like the attached image and I am trying to find a way to make the last column an integer without the exponential notation. I have to do all those "cast" and "round" operations in the CASE expression because the value is stored in a varchar column.

[image: Partial napshot of email body]

In this case, the values in the last column should read as 9611174 and 7289261. The output in a text file or in the query results grid show just as I want them. However, the resultant email with the HTML content has the exponential notation.

Comment: Why are you casting the values as a `float`? It's because you're casting them to a floating point value that you're getting floating point values in your email.

Comment: Larnu got it. You're casting to `float` and [`xs:float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#float) has e-notation.

Comment: I tried casting it as a decimal but the varchar values are like 9611174.00000 and I kept getting an error. Is it possible to do this? I also heard that I could first cast to float and then cast it to int. I've been having a tough time doing that because the resulting int value rounds down rather than up. Hope you can suggest something that can overcome my problem.

Comment: I made a slight change and used `convert(int,cast(MR.RegisterRead as float))` and it works now. Thanks to @Larnu and @AlwaysLearning for helping. Is there a cleaner/shorter way to do this?